# How to get all values in django models?

Tags: python, django

Suppose  I got some queryset say of length 100 `query_objs=[q1,q2,...,q100]` based on the some criteria. How can I  filter out this query set say is_admin=True. I know this query set has is_admin=True 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

you can filter your queryset before calling `values`

```
Entry.objects.filter(is_admin=True).values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
```

Comment: I have a querset=[obj1, ob2, ob3 ...]. How can I filter over this query set. I don't want to make a fresh db call. Actually I am passing queryset to a function. And those queryset may be from different models. But My function is generic.

Comment: Was the queryset evaluated before? If not, you didn't actually hit the DB yet, so go ahead and do so. Moreover, you might be into too much premature optimization, it's OK to hit the DB when you need a specific set of items.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the tips. But I have a function which takes queryset. I am passing a evaluated queryset to it. Evaluation based on the different parameters. But so the function takes different queryset on different ocassion. But  actually the function does the filter on thart queryset based on the is_admin=True

Comment: have a read about querysets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/
in particular, when they get evaluated

Comment: You're not passing a queryset, you're passing a `ValuesQuerySet`. It's a simplified type that doesn't allow any further filtering because the DB has already been hit. @second's point is that you need to do this work on the queryset *before* you call `.values()` on it, so you're actually working with a true `QuerySet`.

Comment: as far as I can tell the question isn't asking about `.values()` at all. @user426795's comment above confirms that

Answer (score 1):

The goal would be to design your app so that the queryset is not evaluated until after the last filter is applied by your function.

eg

```
qs = Entry.objects.filter(...whatever...)
qs = qs.exclude(...whatever...)
qs = qs.filter(...something_else...)
# qs is not evaluated yet

def my_func(some_qs):
    return some_qs.filter(is_admin=True)

qs = my_func(qs)
# qs is still not evaluated yet
```

if you have no choice than to filter an already evaluated queryset, then be aware you can just treat it like any other iterable, eg use the built-in filter function like on a list:

```
admins = filter(lambda x: x.is_admin, my_evaluated_qs)
```